# Comparar fechas en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar

**Buenas, tengo una consulta, ¿Cómo puedo comparar dos fechas en `Android` con `Java` trayendo una de esas fechas de mi `BD` en `MySQL` con `PHP`?

Pues, lo que hago es lo siguiente, traigo la fecha que necesito desde mi BD con el siguiente método:

```
private void traerFecha(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://flmprogamma.com/fechasuscripcion.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("f=")){
                response = response.replaceAll("f=", "");
                formatoBD = response;

                Log.d("RESPONSE", "onResponse: " + response);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ha ocurrido un problema.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            Map<String,String>parms=new HashMap<String, String>();
            int id = new PreferenciaIdUsuario(MainActivity.this).traerValorGuardado();
            String valId = String.valueOf(id);
            parms.put("idUsuario", valId);
            return parms;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Y obtengo la fecha actual con el siguiente método:

```
private void fechaHoyMetodo(){
    Calendar fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mesActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    if(fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 10) {
        formatoHoy = fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + mesActual + "-0" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("FORMATO", "fechaHoyMetodo: " + formatoHoy);
    }else{
        formatoHoy = fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + mesActual + "-" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("FORMATO", "fechaHoyMetodo: " + formatoHoy);
    }
}
```

Tengo dos variables globales en formato `String` para lo que necesito:

```
private String formatoHoy, formatoBD;
```

Ahora bien, lo que necesito es poder comparar esas dos fechas de la siguiente manera:

```
if(formatoHoy >= formatoBD){
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ha excedido la fecha.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
 //otras cosas
}
```

Como ambas variables son de tipo `String` claramente no puedo usar los operadores **>** ó **<** por lo que necesito parsearlas. Intenté esto:

```
private void parsearFechas(){
    fechaHoy = Calendar.getInstance(); //fehca hoy
    fechaBD = Calendar.getInstance(); //fecha BD
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try{
        Date hoy = sdf.parse(formatoHoy);
        fechaHoy.setTime(hoy);

        Log.d("HOYDATE", "parsearFechas: " + fechaHoy);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "parsearFechas: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Donde `fechaHoy` y `fechaBD` son variables globales de tipo `Calendar`:

```
private Calendar fechaHoy, fechaBD;
```

Lo que necesito es preguntar si `fechaHoy` es mayor a la `fechaBD`, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Para la comparación de fechas, recomiendo hacerlo a traves de long que genera el GregorianCalendar con el metodo getTimeInMillis(). Dependiendo de la precisión que busques, deberas poner a 0 los segundos, minutos, u horas.

Comment: Lo he solucionado usando las propiedades `after/before` del objeto `Date` pero gracias por tu sugerencia

Comment: Hola @FranqoBalsamo sería interesante ver tu solución, te sugiero publicarla como respuesta,  te aseguro que sería de mucha ayuda a la comunidad, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues mi solución ha sido, crear dos variables globales:

```
public Calendar fechaHoy, fechaBD;
public String formatoHoy, formatoBD;
```

Y luego crear métodos para la obtención de las fechas:

```
public void traerFecha(final Context contexto){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://flmprogamma.com/fechasuscripcion.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("f=")){
                response = response.replaceAll("f=", "");
                formatoBD = response;
                //Log.d("RESPONSE", "onResponse: " + response);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(contexto,"Ha ocurrido un problema.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            Map<String,String>parms=new HashMap<String, String>();
            int id = new PreferenciaIdUsuario(contexto).traerValorGuardado();
            String valId = String.valueOf(id);
            parms.put("idUsuario", valId);
            return parms;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void fechaHoyMetodo(){
    Calendar fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mesActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    if(fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 10) {
        formatoHoy = fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + mesActual + "-0" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("FORMATO", "fechaHoyMetodo: " + formatoHoy);
    }else{
        formatoHoy = fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + mesActual + "-" + fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("FORMATO", "fechaHoyMetodo: " + formatoHoy);
    }
}
```

Hecho eso, solo quedaba parsear y comparar con after o before:

```
public void parsearFechasYValidar(Context contexto){
    fechaHoy = Calendar.getInstance(); //fecha hoy
    fechaBD = Calendar.getInstance(); //fecha BD
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try{
        Date hoy = sdf.parse(formatoHoy);
        fechaHoy.setTime(hoy);

        Date bd = sdf.parse(formatoBD);
        fechaBD.setTime(bd);

        if(hoy.after(bd)){ //esto pregunta si hoy es una fecha posterior a bd
            cerrarActividadPorSuscripcion();
        }else{
            listaPreciosArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //array de listas
            recyclerListaPrecios = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerListaPrecios); //dibujamos el recycler
            recyclerListaPrecios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ListaPreciosActivity.this));//le decimos dónde está
            recyclerListaPrecios.setHasFixedSize(true);//que corriga los detalles
            listaPreciosPapa();//cargamos los precios con el método
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "parsearFechas: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```